# Why does dojo inlined template html contain strange leading character(s)?

Tags: build, dojo

My actual template html file begins with "<div" but the inlined string has a non-visible character that I can only observe in a hex editor.  I assume this is a known issue with a known workaround?

[image: HEX encoding of inlined template]

Comment: This is due to VS 2012 saving the file with an encoding.  Saving as US-ASCII eliminates this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0xEF,0xBB,0xBF is the UTF-8 encoding of the U+FEFF Byte Order Mark. It is inappropriate to include a BOM in a UTF-8 file—it's meant for byte order specification in encodings that actually care about byte order, like UTF-16. But many Windows-based tools do so anyway because life would be too easy otherwise.

Whatever tool you used to create the template decided to save it encoded as “UTF-8 with faux-BOM”. How you stop it doing that depends on that tool; for text editors there is commonly a choice of encodings at save-as-time; look for “UTF-8 without BOM”.

Alternatively (or additionally!), whatever tool you use to read in the template and create the inlined version needs to recognise and remove the faux-BOM when decoding from UTF-8.